# http: When the client receives a 200, is all response content already in memory

Tags: http

When http client downloads something via GET method and receives status code 200, is all response content already buffered in memory ? Response content maybe quite large, like 1G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status line containing the status code is the first thing that is received, the rest of the data can still be in-flight or not even sent yet.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, 200 just means the request sent by client has succeeded. When client reading the response content streamingly, this connection could still break, so that the client can't read the whole content.

Comment: That's correct. Anything could happen. Server crash, client crash, cable yanked from a machine, and so on.